# Do Carmo, exercise 1.5.14

Tags: differential-geometry

**Exercise:** Let $\alpha: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular parametrized plane curve. Assume there exist $t_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $t_0$ is a maximum of $f(t) = |\alpha(t)|$ (the distance to the origin). Prove that the curvature $k$ at $t_0$ satisfies $|k(t_0)| \ge \dfrac{1}{|\alpha(t_0)|}$

---

**My work so far:**

Since $t_0$ is a maximum of $f(t)$, is also a maximum of $g(t)= f(t)^2 = \alpha(t)\cdot \alpha(t)$ which implies $g^{''}(t_0) < 0 \Longleftrightarrow \alpha^{'}(t_0)\cdot \alpha^{'}(t_0) + \alpha(t_0)\cdot \alpha^{''}(t_0) <0$

Now, if $\theta$ is the angle between $\alpha(t_0), \alpha^{''}(t_0)$, then $$-|\alpha(t_0)|\cdot |\alpha^{''}(t_0)| \le  |\alpha(t_0)|\cdot |\alpha^{''}(t_0)| \cdot \cos(\theta) = \alpha(t_0)\cdot \alpha^{''}(t_0) < - |\alpha^{'}(t_0)|\cdot |\alpha^{'}(t_0)|$$ (1st inequality comes from $\cos (\theta) \ge -1$) So, $$-|\alpha(t_0)|\cdot |\alpha^{''}(t_0)| \le - |\alpha^{'}(t_0)|\cdot |\alpha^{'}(t_0)|$$ $$\implies |\alpha^{''}(t_0)| \ge \dfrac{|\alpha^{'}(t_0)|^2}{|\alpha(t_0)|}$$

But then, if $\phi$ is the angle between $\alpha^{'}(t_0), \alpha^{''}(t_0)$: $$k(t_0) = \dfrac{|\alpha^{''}(t_0) \times \alpha^{'}(t_0)|}{|\alpha^{'}(t_0)|^3} = \dfrac{|\alpha^{''}(t_0)|\cdot |\alpha^{'}(t_0)|\cdot \sin(\phi)}{|\alpha^{'}(t_0)|^3} \ge \dfrac{\sin(\phi)}{|\alpha(t_0)|}$$

---

So, my question is how to finish the exercise.

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 2):

Reparametrize $\alpha$ by arclength: (or assume it wlog)

Define:
$\beta : s\in (0,s_b) \to \Bbb{R^2}$
Where $s= \int_a^{t} |\alpha'(u)|du$

Then from the conditions given, we know:

$$|\beta' (s_0) |^2 +\beta (s_0) \cdot \beta '' (s_0) <0$$

Since it is parametrized by arclength, $|\beta '(s_0)|=1$ and $\beta ''(s_0) = k(s_0) \hat {N} (s_0)$, where $\hat N$ is the unit normal vector. Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\beta (s_0)$ and $\hat {N} (s_0)$, then we have:

$$-1> |\beta (s_0)|  |k(s_0)| \cos \theta$$

so $-1 \leq \cos \theta <0$

$\frac {-1}{\cos \theta} \geq 1$

$$|k(s_0)|> \frac {-1} { |\beta (s_0)|   \cos \theta} \geq \frac 1{ |\beta (s_0)| }$$

Since $\beta (s_0)= \alpha (t_0)$ and curvature is independent on reparametrization, we have proven the desired result.